# Sum using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I want to add up polygamous women in my data by region.
Here is my code :

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

database_path = "dataformap.csv"
database = pd.read_csv(database_path)
#Creating a geodataframe
points = gpd.points_from_xy(database["longitude"], database["latitude"], crs="EPSG:4326")
map = gpd.GeoDataFrame (database, geometry=points) 
database.set_index('geo_bj2017')
database['polygamy']=database.groupby('geo_bj2017')['polygam'].sum()
```

Here is what I obtain :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsIbk.png)

Here is what database.head() gives

```
0   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
1   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
2   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
3   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
4   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
```

Is there a way to make this work on python ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: BTW, this instruction does nothing: `database.set_index('geo_bj2017')` as you don't collect  the return

Comment: Ah thank you, so what should I do to get a table (that I can collect) with the index being geobj_2017 ?

Comment: Pandas documentation is pretty good, [check set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) out

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the data, assuming the problem comes from NaNs in the data...

Instead of using a normal sum, you should use a "nan-safe" sum, like [nansum from numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) like
`database['polygamy']=database.groupby('geo_bj2017')['polygam'].agg(np.nansum)`

Note however, that for me `groupby().sum()` already operates with NA without issues:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0,1], 'b':[1, 2, 3, pd.NA]})
>>> df.groupby('a').agg(np.nansum)
   b
a
0  4
1  2

>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0,1], 'b':[1, 2, 3, np.nan] })
>>> df.groupby('a').sum()
     b
a
0  4.0
1  2.0
```

**EDIT** When groupingby/sum, you get an aggregation, not a "column" to paste. Example with partial data. I am missing the headers in your table.

```
x="""index x y polygam year geo_bj2017 
0   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori 
1   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori 
2   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori 
3   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori 
4   7.283433    2.12276 1   2017    alibori """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x),sep='\s+')
df.groupby('geo_bj2017')['polygam'].sum()
>>> df.groupby('geo_bj2017')['polygam'].sum()
geo_bj2017
alibori    5
Name: polygam, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried it and it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: I edited my post and put an image o what database.head() gives

Comment: Can you paste the head as text? An image is impossible to copypaste

Comment: latitude longitude polygam year geo_bj2017 geometry polygamy
0 7.283433 2.12276 1 2017 alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
1 7.283433 2.12276 1 2017 alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
2 7.283433 2.12276 1 2017 alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
3 7.283433 2.12276 1 2017 alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN
4 7.283433 2.12276 1 2017 alibori POINT (2.12276 7.28343) NaN

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make tables here

Comment: just edit your question and use triple tilde thingie ``` to set it as code

Comment: Is there an alternative on python to create the column I need since group.by sum doesn't do that?